# Eclipse CDT:Launch failed binary not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

- I have started using Eclipse CDT in Ubuntu 13.04. I installed the CDT
  using the **help->Install** Software way. After building a project i
  am not able to run it as a C/C++ application. A pop up message says
  that **Launch failed,Binary not found.** I looked up several times on
  the web, but could not find any answer that could resolve the
  problem.

Can anyone point in the direction :

- **What needs to be checked for troubleshooting such issues**.
- **how to decide whether the problem lies in installation or some configurations related to the project.?**

Comment: Look at the links at the right in the **Related** category. You're not that first one asking this here. Please first search before asking a new question!

Comment: I tried them all but i was not able to resolve the problem using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up a compiler and add it to your path. I recommend using [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) (you will need the g++ and make packages). Add `C:\cygwin64\bin` to your path for 64 bit, `C:\cygwin\bin` for 32 bit. To add something to your path, right-click `My Computer` and click `Properties`.
In the window that opens up, click `Advanced System Settings` (in the left column).
From there, click the `Environment Variables` button. Scroll down to `path` in the bottom section, and double click it. Add the path there (the list is separated by semicolons.)

Comment: i am using it on Ubuntu ,and G++ compiler is already added in the settings.

Comment: Do you have `make` installed?

Comment: In the project folder ,there are two folders, Release and Debug, both have the make files.Also I can see only the .o file, not any binary files anywhere.

Comment: Hmmm. IDK then, interesting. Any build errors?

Comment: There was no build error.I'll see if i could change some settings to make it work.